# Difference in size shown by "du" command and "get info" on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, directory, filesize, du

Run the command "du -ch /Applications" on terminal, note down its size.
Now look at the size of /Applications folder from "Get Info" option.
There is a major difference size shown. Same is true for any other folder.
What is the reason for this difference, which one of it is the exact size?

Comment: Try using du -k. If I remember my MacBook Pro correctly, du defaults to 500 byte block size for some reason.

Comment: It does default to 512 bytes or `$BLOCKSIZE` (documented in the man page) - this convention goes back decades, I guess probably because old Unix filesystems used 512-byte blocks?  If you use `-h` the block size is ignored though.

Answer (score 4):

In recent OS X versions Finder uses base 10 (1 MB = 1000 KB, etc) as storage manufacturers do, rather than base 2 (1 MiB = 1024 KiB) as `du -h` does.

This is a duplicate of [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/125025/why-do-finder-and-du-report-different-file-size) - hopefully it can be closed as duplicate once it's moved...

Comment: I am not sure the reason is this because the difference is much more than what may come because of base 10 and base 2. The outputs for /Applications folder on my machine are: from "Get Info" 925.3 MB, from "du -ck /Applications" 477596, from "du -c /Applications" 955192 and from "du -ch /Applications" 466M

Comment: Perhaps you've got lots of data in non-data forks? As far as I know du isn't fork-aware but the Finder is.  I'd suggest you dig into individual subdirectories of /Applicstions to see if this is the case, or if it may be related to filesystem compression as the other answer mentions.  Probably best to start with a small Apple app.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the system provided `du`, or some `du` you installed from the source?

The vast difference in the size shown can be because of the file system compression, not seen by some of the BSD tools. It basically works by putting a compressed version of a file in the resource fork of the file, keeping the data fork empty. When the file is read, the content is automatically decomporessed. But some of the BSD API reports the bare size of the data fork, thus missing the size of the real data in the resource fork.

See [this explanation](http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2009/08/mac-os-x-10-6.ars/3#) for more details.

I believe the standard `/usr/bin/du` takes care of this file system compression, so if you do not use MacPorts or Fink to install an old version of `du` this should not be the cause of the problem ...

Comment: I am using system provided du